# How to get coefficients from princomp object in R?

Tags: r, pca

Basically, I want to manually compute what `predict(princomp(somedata))` produces.

In order to do that I need to have coefficients matrix so that

```
newdata %*% coefficients
```

would produce the predicted values of each component.

Can anybody give me a clue to get the coefficients?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you read the documentation on the `princomp` function, via `?princomp` you'll see that there is a section titled "Value" that describes the components of the object returned.

The piece you are looking for is probably the loadings.

Additionally, if you type `stats:::predict.princomp` at the console you can see for yourself precisely what R is doing when you call `predict`.

Comment: Exactly what I needed. I tried predict.princomp without the prefix. So my confusion began. Thanks.

Comment: @david No prob. A good strategy for this kind of problem is to type `methods(predict)`, and then try `stats::predict.princomp` if there's no asterisk, and use 3 colons when there is an asterisk.

Answer (score 3):

The particular calculation done by `predict` in this case is `scale(newdata, object$center, object$scale) %*% object$loadings`, where `object` is the object returned by `princomp`. There's no way to reduce this to a single matrix multiplication, as in the general case `newdata` must be rescaled to match the original data.

Comment: Thanks. But based on that, you can still compute coefficients including intercept for unscaled data with center and scale known.